# Maximum update depth exceeded error on React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, setstate, asyncstorage

I was trying to get data stored in asyncstorage using multiGet command for lastName, imagePath and  phoneNumber fields. The first two fields i got successfully. However, when I add phoneNumber field it shows the error:

"Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly call setState..."

I have tried  different procedures as suggested by some online forum (including almost similar question on stackOverflow) but all to no avail. Can someone help me out please.

NB: I am using React Native.

This is the initial values for the data i stored in the AsyncStorage

```
const [imagePath, setImagePath ] = React.useState(null)
const [state, setState ] = React.useState(initialState)
const [firstName, setFirstName] = React.useState('')
const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = React.useState('')
const [email, setEmail] = React.useState('')
const [lastName, setLastName] = React.useState(null)

const userData = {
  firstName: firstName,
  lastName: lastName,
  email: email,
  phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
  imagePath: imagePath
}

const initialStateData = {
  orderStatuses: state.orderStatuses,
  passwordChanges: state.passwordChanges,
  specialOffers: state.specialOffers,
  newsletter: state.newsletter
}
const firstData = ['user', JSON.stringify(userData)]
const secondData = ['checkbox', JSON.stringify(initialStateData)]
```

This is how i save the data to AsyncStorage:

```
const saveData = async () => {
  try {

    await AsyncStorage.multiSet([firstData, secondData])
    alert('Data successfully saved!')
  } catch {
    alert('Failed to saved data!')
  }
}
```

And this is how I get the data from AsyncStorage:

```
const getData = async () => {
  try {
    const user = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(['user', 'checkbox'])
    const userPersonalData = JSON.parse(user[0][1])
    const userCheckbox = JSON.parse(user[1][1])

    //console.log(userPersonalData.lastName)

    if (userPersonalData.lastName != undefined) {
     setLastName(userPersonalData.lastName)
    }
    if (userPersonalData.imagePath != undefined ) {
    setImagePath(userPersonalData.imagePath)
    } 
    if (userPersonalData.phoneNumber != undefined) {
      const userPhoneNumber = userPersonalData.phoneNumber


      setPhoneNumber((userPhoneNumber) => (userPhoneNumber))
    } 
    if (userCheckbox != null) {
      setState ({
        orderStatuses: userCheckbox.orderStatuses,
        passwordChanges: userCheckbox.passwordChanges,
        specialOffers: userCheckbox.specialOffers,
        newsletter: userCheckbox.newsletter
      })
    }


    console.log(userPersonalData)

  } catch (e) {
    Alert.alert('Failed to fetch data!')
    console.log(e)
  }
}

React.useEffect(() => {
  getData()
}, [])
```

Note that i used MaskTextInput component of reactive-mask-text. Here is the implementation of the component:

```
<View style={styles.inputFieldWrapper}>
   <Text style={styles.inputFieldsTitle}>Phone number</Text>
   <MaskedTextInput
     mask='+1 (999) 999-9999' 
     style={styles.inputFields}
     value={phoneNumber}
     onChangeText={(data) => {setPhoneNumber(data)}}
     placeholder='+1 ([000]) [000]-[0000]'
   />
</View>
```

NB: The error is only shown when i tried to get stored data for phoneNumber and populate the phone Number field.

Thank you.